# Correct place of apostrophe: friend's or friends'

Tags: grammar, apostrophe

A quick Google search (actually I use Duckduckgo but "a quick Duck or DDG search" would sound weird...) showed that "friend's" was a bit more common, whereas a Google user manual or tutorial used "friends' " and I (maybe biasly) assume them to use (more) correct grammar. The sentence used in the Google user manual was:
"See **friends'** locations on a map"

(see this link https://support.google.com/plus/answer/3302509?hl=en)

Comment: Sorry bout that.

Comment: No worries, dupes are sometimes hard to find. If the suggested dupe answers your question, please click on the ["That solved my problem"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250981/203101) link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Friend's* means of a single friend, *friends'* means of multiple friends. General rule: for a single form - **noun+'s**, for plural form - **noun+s'**.

Comment: Thanks, it seems so obvious now...And, well, it actually is.